# What's the needed knowledge to play Over The Hills and Far Away - Nightwish version?

Tags: electric-guitar

What's the needed knowledge to play Over The Hills and Far Away - Nightwish version?
I want, if possible, to jump over all the stuff I don't need, to only concentrate, focus on playing the stuff that I need, to only play this song and then die. xD Maybe I'm gonna need to play other songs to get to this song.
Do you have a *to-do list*? I'm a total beginner. I just know a couple of chords, and know how to read tabs. I'm learning how to play electric guitar with John Petrucci. Please give me that advice. I need light against the boredom. 
Thanks!

PD: I like the song by Gary Moore too, Over the hills...

Comment: Hi Frank. This type of question is not a good fit here as there is no correct answer. You could play this with no knowledge at all, or you could approach it from a theoretical background, or anything in between. Please read our questions on getting started on guitar.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that hard to play, even for a beginner. Although I think you should stick with the theory, that's a whole other debate that I do not intend on sparking here. If you're getting bored with theory and you want to learn a song to stay motivated, this might actually be a good one.

Get the tabs and take it slow. I have found this video:

You can see the guy play it and the tabs are on the video. Take it one bar at a time and play it slowly, then move on once you are comfortable. For the rhythm section you only need palm muting and a few power chords; I'm sure both are explained in the first chapter of Petrucci's course, and you can find many youtube videos on that.

The solo also seems pretty straightforward; I listened to it quickly and it seems to only have one slide and maybe some hammer-ons and pull offs.

I'd say that's enough to get you started. Start with the rhythm, you should have it down relatively quickly. Then, attack the lead guitar slowly and finish with the solo. Watch other videos and tabs, maybe you'll find someone who plays it differently or who explains it better.